# Can a class expose a number without instantiating it?

Tags: c++

A class can expose types without instantiating it. For example:

```
class bar {
  typedef int GET_TYPE;
};

template<class T>
void foo() {
  typename T::GET_TYPE t;
  // do something with t
}

foo<bar>();
```

Can a integer number be exposed in a similar way? In the sense that template parameters can be either types or built-in types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enum` is good for that.

```
class bar
{
     enum { MyNumericValue = 17, };
};
```

This only works for integral values, but works with all versions of C++.

For non-integral values, see [CatPlusPlus's modern solution (C++11-only)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10938213/103167).

Comment: Static const is better solution I suppose. It works at least for all built-in types.

Comment: @Frank: Nope, but if you wanted multiple values exported, use commas, not semicolons, between them.

Comment: @Forgottn: But `static const` requires a definition for the member in exactly one compilation unit, see `[class.static.data]` in the various versions of the Standard.  Which may violate the "without instantiation" part of the question.

Comment: @Frank, the comma is omitted for the last member. It just brings more convinience while declaring large enums to have all members with commas.

Comment: @BenVoigt I suppose *without intstantiation* was a part of description of the type exposion.

Comment: The class is really *never* instantiated, only static member functions. But now I need an integer from it as well. The `enum` thing seems to work

Comment: @Frank: Wait, did you mean that `bar` isn't instantiated, or `int` isn't?

Comment: @Frank Oops. Missed it. static const built-in types (not sure for all PODs) can be defined at the place of declararion, it's okay for them to violate the rule. But, now when I see without instantiation, the question looks weird for me.

Comment: No, `bar` is never instantiated. `bar` should expose a number while no instance exists

Comment: @Forgottn: C++11 clarified the rule.  If you *odr-used* the member, e.g. by taking its address, then exactly one definition would be required.

Comment: @Frank: Without C++11, you can replace `constexpr` in CatPlusPlus's answer by `const`... but then it isn't a compile-time integral expression anymore (without C++11 that is, with C++11 `const` and `constexpr` behave the same for this case).

Comment: Yep. So if you'll once need a float or double, or a char array you'd better use `static const`. For integral types both solutions will work, and I suppose the enum will be even better in terms that it will surely be accessible at compile time.

Comment: Then its difficult to put the right answer tag. I put it on this one, since @BenVoigt was a tick earlier. Thanks all!

Comment: @Forgottn: only *integral* types can be *initialized* (not *defined*) inside the class braces. The *definition* still goes outside of the class definition in a single translation unit, and is only required if the constant is *odr-used* (used as an *lvalue* expression)

Comment: @dribeas: Since C++11, *literal types* can be used with `constexpr` and the `brace-or-equal-initializer` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use a static data member.

```
struct foo {
    static constexpr int something = 42;
};

// ... use foo::something ...
```

Comment: `constexpr` is valid only for C++0x, otherwise it will be `const`

Comment: According to the Standard, you may still need to define `int foo::something;` exactly once.